# Custom plugin - HOW TO GET SAVE CONFIGURATION VALUE

Tags: magento-1.7, configuration

I have my custom module with magento 1.7 which has configuration page in checkout tab in admin panel. I have different fields like text,textarea,select on form. I want to get these values when I click on 'Save Config' button.
Although I Have helpers and models of my module. But I'm not getting understand how/what to make a new helper/model file and what function will be to get these field values after clicking on 'Save Config' button.
I have system.xml file of my module.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

`Mage::getStoreConfig('section/group/field');`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, would you please elaborate a little bit where to use this function. Actually I want send form values to a third party using curl when the user clicks on 'Save Config' button on the configuration page.
Thanks

Comment: The code in the answer will retrieve the value from storage according to the path specified. Assign that to a variable and then use the variable in your cURL message.